# Problems with user macros after updating confluence from 3.5 to 5.4.4

Tags: macros, confluence

i've upgraded a confluence-system from 3.5 to 5.4.4.

There is a user-macro called 'faq' which was used very often
it just looks like this:

```
{panel:title=$param0}
$body
{panel}
```

and formats input to something like this:

[image: format example]

after the update editing of the headline (param0) is not possible - error message that there is no metadata ... so i updated the macro to use this code:

```
## Macro title: faq
## Macro has a body: Y
## Body processing: Selected body processing option
## Output: Selected output option
##
## Developed by: me
## Date created: 05/06/2014
## Installed by: me
## @param 0:title=Name|type=string|required=true|desc=Headline der FAQ
<div class="panel" style="border-width: 1px;"><div class="panelHeader" style="border-bottom-width: 1px;"><b>$param0</b></div>
<div class="panelContent">
$body
</div>
```

this works, but any other macro inside the body wont work anymore:

[image: formating inside body not working]

can someone please help me to get the body content in the right format again?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the body content displayed is old fashioned wiki-markup.

You can't use wiki markup in Confluence 5.x.

Ensure that the **macro body processing** is set to **Rendered**:

[image: macro body processing]

After that, you should be able to nest macros within the macro body like so:

[image: editing in the user macro]

It will be rendered as so:

[image: result]

**Update:**

To migrate macros from Confluence 3.x or below, consider this post: [On converting wiki markup based user macros for use with Confluence 4](http://davidsimpson.me/2012/01/24/on-converting-wiki-markup-based-user-macros-for-use-with-confluence-4/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the problem is that we migrated from 3.5 to 5.4.4 and the faq-macro wont show me its content rendered - i need to edit every content to get them renderd again

Comment: See the update. Also, when you edit the page, does it wrap the body in a wiki markup macro? What does the edit page look like? Perhap you need to copy the body and then paste it back into the page with the "Insert Wiki Markup" option.